# What is the purpose of Hindu girls attire?

Tags: belief, practice

Why Hindu girls or women should wear Bangles, Nosepin, earrings, Gezze, and even flowers behind head? Also, toe ring after marriage?

Thaali is something we all know it shows that they are married and it is proof. What about others?

Comment: This is a question about Indian cultural traditions, not a question about the Hindu religion.